# How to redirect default program output?

Tags: python, windows, shell, pipe

I am trying to pipe output of my python scripts to pygmentize.

In registry I've set it like this:

```
"C:\Anaconda\python.exe" "%1"%* | pygmentize
```

not working (not piping anything at all), what is wrong?

Comment: The command line template in the registry gets used by `ShellExecuteEx` to build the command line to pass to `CreateProcess`. It doesn't support classic shell operators for redirecting standard I/O. You have to use the CMD shell for that, e.g. `"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /c ""C:\Anaconda\python.exe" "%1" %* | "path\to\pygmentize.exe""`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use powershell for this

```
C:\ PowerShell -Command " python [yourprogram.py] | pygmentize -l py3t"
```

> -Command
>
> Executes the specified commands (and any parameters) as though they were typed at the Windows PowerShell command prompt, and then exits, unless the NoExit parameter is specified. Essentially, any text after -Command is sent as a single command line to PowerShell (this is different from how -File handles parameters sent to a script).
>
> The value of Command can be "-", a string. or a script block. If the value of Command is "-", the command text is read from standard input.
>   Script blocks must be enclosed in braces ({}). You can specify a script block only when running PowerShell.exe in Windows PowerShell. The results of the script are returned to the parent shell as deserialized XML objects, not live objects.
>
> If the value of Command is a string, Command must be the last parameter in the command, because any characters typed after the command are interpreted as the command arguments.
>   To write a string that runs a Windows PowerShell command, use the format:
>
> `"& {<command>}"`
>
> where the quotation marks indicate a string and the invoke operator (&) causes the command to be executed.

The above documentation for `Command` can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: would you link some documentation for powershell for this please? or elaborate a bit, can't get it working...

Comment: @Bob I added it!

Comment: Piping standard I/O in PowerShell is very different from a typical shell. It sets itself up as a middleman that decodes using the current codepage, substitutes LF => CRLF line endings, and then re-encodes to write to the other side of the pipe. PowerShell needs an operator for a classic, binary pipe. Until then I just use `cmd /c`.